# Autosys box issue

Tags: linux, unix, autosys

I am having an autosys box job-  auto_task_box which have 3 child jobs

```
:  auto_task1_wd   - runs in every 5 mins monday to friday
:  auto_task2_dly   - runs on 02:00 on every day
:  auto_task3_sa    - runs at 03:00 on every saturday
```

Issue is after scheduling is after the Ist run of auto_task1_wd, the box will wait for completion of auto_task2_dly and auto_task3_sa  so the next iteration of auto_task1_wd ie after 5 mins won't happen.

How would I tackle this issue?

I am using autosys R11 in linux.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the three jobs should run independent from each other.  In this case I would not use a box at all, but just three separate tasks, as I always tend to think of boxes as a way of ensuring relationships between tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer, these jobs should not be grouped into the same box. Boxes are container for jobs with like starting conditions. It is a very bad idea to have date time conditions for jobs in a box. You will have some unexpected runs that way.